# Unable to scrape description of webpage in Scrapy

Tags: python, html, web, web-scraping, scrapy

I want scrape data using Scrapy and here is the link

https://bbdealz.com/product/1000pcs-jigsaw-puzzle-7550cm-with-storage-bag-wooden-paper-puzzles-educational-toys-for-children-bedroom-decoration-stickers/

[image: screenshot]

I use this code to get the Description

```
'description': response.css('#tab-description p::text').extract(),
```

But the response was

```
description': ['    ', 'None  ', '  ', 'Unisex  ', '  ', '12-15 Years  ', '  ', 'Grownups  ', '  ', 'Paper  ', '  ', 'Landscape  ', '  ', 'SMW783   ']
```

It ignores
`<strong>` and `<br>` tags.

I need the output like this

```
<p>    <strong>Brand Name: </strong>None  <br>  <strong>Gender: </strong>Unisex  <br>  <strong>Age Range: </strong>12-15 Years  <br>  <strong>Age Range: </strong>Grownups  <br>  <strong>Material: </strong>Paper  <br>  <strong>Style: </strong>Landscape  <br>  <strong>Model Number: </strong>SMW783   </p>
```

Comment: do you mean you want the actual html tags and not just the text?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using xpath:

I tested this and it seems to work:

```
for element in response.xpath("//div[@id='tab-description']/p"):
    values = element.xpath("./text()").getall()
    labels = element.xpath("./strong/text()").getall()
    values = [i for i in values if i.strip()]
    data = {labels[i]:values[i] for i in range(len(labels))}
    print(data)
```

output: `{'Brand Name: ': 'None  ', 'Gender: ': 'Unisex  ', 'Age Range: ': 'Grownups  ', 'Material: ': 'Paper  ', 'Style: ': 'Landscape  ', 'Model Number: ': 'SMW783   '}`

---

---

#### This is just the html:

```
a = response.xpath("//div[@id='tab-description']/p").get()
print(a)
```

output

```
<p>    <strong>Brand Name: </strong>None  <br>  <strong>Gender: </strong>Unisex  <br>  <strong>Age Range: </strong>12-15 Years  <br>  <strong>Age Range: </strong>Grownups  <br>  <strong>Material: </strong>Paper  <br>  <strong>S
tyle: </strong>Landscape  <br>  <strong>Model Number: </strong>SMW783   </p>
```

Comment: Hello, this one response.xpath("//div[@id='tab-description']/p").get() give the html but it also return too much other div content. I have added the screenshot. Can you please check again ? screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/EA0CLtC.png Regards

Comment: @HannahJames  The first block of code is how you get the values

Comment: is it possible to get output with full html inside div like ? <p>    <strong>Brand Name: </strong>None  <br>  <strong>Gender: </strong>Unisex  <br>  <strong>Age Range: </strong>12-15 Years  <br>  <strong>Age Range: </strong>Grownups  <br>  <strong>Material: </strong>Paper  <br>  <strong>Style: </strong>Landscape  <br>  <strong>Model Number: </strong>SMW783   </p>

Comment: @HannahJames  that is what the bottom portion does

Answer (score 0):

When /text() in XPath or ::text in CSS fails to produce the desired result, I use another library.

to install it.

```
pip3 install html2text
```

example

```
from html2text import HTML2Text
h = HTML2Text()
h.ignore_links = True
h.ignore_images = True
h.ignore_emphasis = True

#Inside the scrapy project
'description': h.handle(response.css('#tab-description p').get()).strip()

yield ....
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it work

```
import scrapy
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Google(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'google'
    start_urls = ['https://bbdealz.com/product/funny-sports-game-2m-3m-4m-5m-6m-diameter-outdoor-rainbow-umbrella-parachute-toy-jump-sack-ballute-play-game-mat-toy-kids-gift/',]
    def parse(self, response):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body, 'html.parser')
        yield {
        'title': response.css('h1::text').get(),
        'description': soup.select_one('#tab-description').select_one('p'),
        }
```

Regards